# How do I start/stop failed upstart job?

Tags: java, upstart, process

I have an upstart script in `/etc/init/myexample.conf`. This job basically runs a java jar file. Normally, I can start and stop this using `sudo start myexample` and `sudo stop myexample`.

I changed the jar file and introduced an error that caused the jar to crash. After starting the jar with `sudo start myexample`, I see the errors in my log file.

Now I would like to stop the upstart job and replace the jar file with a working one again. I have seen two scenarios:

1. `sudo stop myexample` hangs indefinitely (at least 10 minutes). I also cannot start the job again with `sudo start myexample`, I receive the error `start: Job is already running: myexample`.
2. `sudo start myexample` hangs indefinitely, and `sudo stop myexample` gives `stop: Job has already been stopped: myexample`.

I can also run the jar manually from the command line.

`pgrep -lf myexample` and `pgrep -l myexample` return nothing. `pgrep -l java` shows other java processes that are running, but not the failed one corresponding to myexample. Upstart thinks the process is running, but it is not.

How can I get the upstart job running again, without a reboot?

---

`/etc/init/myexample.conf`:

```
description "myexample"  

start on runlevel [2345]  
stop on shutdown  

respawn
respawn limit 3 120

expect daemon

setuid exampleuser

script     
    chdir /home/exampleuser/ 
    java -jar /home/exampleuser/example.jar
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill the process.

You can kill the process (if running) by:

```
pkill <process_name>
```

Or

```
killall <process_name>
```

This will match the process name only, if you want to match the whole command line, use (with extreme care):

```
pkill -f <part_of_the_command>
```

---

So in you case:

```
sudo pkill myexample
```

should do.

You can be sure beforehand, by running:

```
pgrep -l myexample
```

to check the process ID to make sure no other process coincides with the name.

On a different note, after finding the PID with `pgrep -l myexample`, you can kill the process with `kill` too:

```
kill PID
```

Comment: `pgrep -l myexample` returns nothing. `pgrep -l java` shows the java processes that have been started by running upstart jobs, but does not have a corresponding entry for myexample, the upstart job that failed.

Comment: @mattm That means the process is not running..

Comment: @mattm Edit your question and the upstart script you are talking about..

Comment: @mattm Yes..also whats the output of `pgrep -lf myexample` ?

Comment: I updated the question with script. Also `pgrep -lf myexample` shows nothing.